# How to parse formula values as text in Excel via C#

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet-function

I have to parse out some data from a MS Excel file.

The cells that I need to grab data out of have formula text as its value.

For example:

```
Sheet 2 [A1].Value = "$50"
Sheet 1 [A1].Formula = "='Sheet2'!A1"
```

When I grab the value for `Sheet1 [A1]`, I get `='Sheet2'!A1`, not `$50`.

Is there a way to get the text value after formula calculation from `Sheet1[A1]` using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I got using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as mentioned by Rup

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string fileName = @"C:\TestSheet.xls";
Application xlApp = new Application();
Workbook book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
Worksheet sheet = xlApp.Worksheets[1];
Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1");
Console.WriteLine(range.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which member of [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms281150%28v=Office.11%29.aspx) handles that set but I'd guess it equates to [Value2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and not a general input in the same way as the spreadsheet. Try:

```
Sheet1[A1].Formula = "='Sheet2'!A1";
Console.Out.WriteLine(Sheet1[A1].Value2);
```

to explicitly set that as a forumula. You might also need to trigger a recalculation but I'd expect not.